# Python scipy.optimize.leastsq

Tags: c#, python, scipy, levenberg-marquardt

Is there any easy implementation of the function Levenberg-Marquardtoptimize.leastsq in C#?
I am trying to use MinPack but since the input parameters are different I am getting different results.
Internally, python calls the function leastsq in the file [minpack.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L256), that down below calls another function but this time with more input parameters _minpack._lmdif.
I have found in the file [_minpack.h](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/__minpack.h#L432) a function that after some magical steps (for me), calls a fortran function lmdif with even more parameters.
Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but maybe try using `scipy.optimize.leastsq`? [According to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) it

> Return the point which minimizes the sum of squares of M (non-linear) equations in N unknowns given a starting estimate, x0, using a modification of the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.

Hopefully it's not too much of a modification ...

Comment: I am using scipy.optimize.leastsq on Python, what I would like is a function in C# with the same input parameters that returns the same results I am getting on python. I have tried Alglib and MinPack for C# but those require dozens of input parameters, and the results are not the same.